# Ionic 2 keep sidemenu icon after navCtrl push

Tags: angular, ionic2

When I navigate to a page using navCtrl.push, sidemenu icon (hamburger) is lost, and back icon is appearing instead of the sidemenu icon.

What I want to do, is to keep the sidemenu icon (put it on the right side of the ion-navbar), and when pushing a page to navCtrl, have both back button and sidemenu icon.

I use this piece of code in all pages:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle right>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Post Offices</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

And I use:

```
this.navCtrl.push(Page)
```

And it works fine (I lose the menu icon though, but there is no other problem).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add attribute `persistent="true"` to `<ion-menu>` then `menuToggle` button will be available on all views. You can find more details here in the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/Menu/#navigation-bar-behavior)