# Showing back button and right side menu in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

SO I am creating an application with Ionic 2. When I navigate using 'navController.push' I go to the correct page and the back button appears (as expected), but it also hides my view specific nav buttons in the header. This is as expected too.. but I am trying to override the 'hidden' property that Ionic applies on one of my buttons, does anybody know how to do this?

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="clarity">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button ion-button right menuToggle="itemHierarchy">
      <ion-icon name="list"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Topic View</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the solution in my other [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40111156/ionic-2-keep-sidemenu-icon-after-navctrl-push/40112921#40112921)

So, this is a duplicate.

Anyway, you need to add attribute persistent="true" to `<ion-menu>`. Then menuToggle button will be available on all views. You can find more details here in the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/Menu/#navigation-bar-behavior)

Comment: Thanks!!! perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your buttons inside of an `ion-buttons` tag.

Example:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="clarity">

    <button ion-button right menuToggle="itemHierarchy">
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button>
        <ion-icon name="list"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-title>Topic View</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: Adding the button inside of 'ion-buttons' makes the button appear.. but when I add a 'menuToggle' property to the button it doesn't appear anymore.. if I add (click) to the button it also adds the 'hidden' property